# How to create a List of fractions?

Tags: java, list, sorting, comparable, rational-numbers

I need a way of putting a fraction into an `ArrayList`. I am having problems however because I'm not sure how I could do this in a way that I could later compare them so they can be sorted.

Note: I will be using 4 or more fractions and I'm not too sure how to (if its possible) to use the comparable class to do it for more than 2.

For example:
I need to input 1/1 , 3/4 , 7/4 , 2/8

I then need to sort them (Using the list) from the smallest to the greatest.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: well can you show us what you already have?

Comment: Do you want to preserve the original representation of the fraction, or is it okay if they are converted to a floating point number?

Comment: I don't really have much worth showing because this is the start of a project. And I need to preserve the representation for visual purposes but I guess it wouldn't make much of a difference if it was converted to work out the  ordering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public class Fraction implements Comparable<Fraction> {
   private int x1, x2; // implement get/set

   public int compareTo(Fraction o) {
       double tmp = Math.abs((double)x1 / x2 - (double)o.x1 / o.x2);
       if (tmp < 0) return -1;
       if (tmp < 1e-9) return 0;
       return 1;
   }
}
```

Now:

```
ArrayList<Fraction> f;
Collections.sort(f);
```

Answer (score 2):

Create a class called Fraction which stores two variables: numerator and denominator.
You can then make an ArrayList of Fractions.

If you'd like to sort them easily, your best bet is to have it implement `Comparable`.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it two ways first you can take fractions as float value otherwise make a class representing the fraction value then make another class implement **Interface Comparator**.And then use **Collections** to sort.